# Why $\sum_n E(\xi_n^2\wedge1)<\infty \Rightarrow \sum_n 1_{\{\xi_n>1\}}<\infty$ for independent, symmetric random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, random-walk

> Let $\xi_1, \xi_2,...$ be independent, symmetric random variables. Then 
>   $\sum_n E(\xi_n^2\wedge1)<\infty \Rightarrow \sum_n 1_{\{\xi_n>1\}}<\infty$ a.s..

This is a step in **Theorem 4.17** from *Foundations of Modern Probability* edition 2 by *Olav Kallenberg*.

It says it can be derived from Fubini's theorem but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E\sum_n I_{\xi_n >1}=\sum P(\xi_n >1) \leq  \sum E(\xi_n^{2} \wedge 1)<\infty$ because $E(\xi_n^{2} \wedge 1) \geq E(\xi_n^{2} \wedge 1)I_{\xi_n >1} \geq (1\wedge 1) P(\xi_n >1)$. This implies that $\sum_n I_{\xi_n >1}<\infty$ almost surely.